# Visual Basic .NET Dynamic updating Textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I just started to study Visual Basic .NET. I would like to build a dynamic system log text box.

When program is passing one point of code or function, a textbox in another form is updating with the system log.

For example, when the program starts, it appends "System start" to the textbox in another form. When the program starts to use the "cal" function, then the program appends "System: start to cal data" on the textbox in another form.

However, I am not really sure how to update this system log dynamically. Do I need to use threading? Can I do it without threading? Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: I guess the simple answer is to just update the text property of that textbox at each different event.  For example during your cal function just do somthing like

     textbox1.text = "System: start to cal data" . 

It sounds like you just need to read a few beginner tutorials on VB.net.  Maybe im misinterpreting what you are wanting to do exactly.

Comment: Well if it were me. I'd update a log object. It should have an OnChangeEvent. In that you add some code to deal with it. Write to display, windows event log, a file, a database etc. Can't see any need for threading if your main app is displaying the log in it's own UI thread. Now if you were writing out to something external such as a file or a socket (to drive a logging form app), then Throw log requests in to a queue, and pop them off as they get communicated would be a nice thread.

Comment: Mertis thanks for answering my question. I am using refresh function to updating system message. However, I eventually want to update system log without using refresh. :D

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mertis's suggestion, what you can do is to fire a code which concatenates details to your textbox whenever an object is called/code is executed

for example, a function was executed:

```
         Function sampleFunc()
         .....

           Textbox1.text = Textbox1.Text & vbnewline & DateTime.Now & _
           " a Function was Executed"

          End Function
```

Note that I added a datetimenow, in case you needed time details.